# Pass a procedure name dynamically

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Is it possible to pass a name of a procedure dynamically within another procedure?

The procedure name is stored in a table and based on criteria the name will be different.

If it is possible how would I accomplish this?

So far I have something like this:

```
SET $proc = CONCAT('CALL ',$queryString);

PREPARE stmt FROM CONCAT('CALL ', $queryString);

EXECUTE stmt;
```

Comment: `PREPARE stmt FROM $proc;` and then `EXECUTE stmt;` should do the trick since $proc has been set with the SQL statement (your procedure CALL) already.

Comment: What's the problem with your code?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty close, just use correct prepared statement syntax:

```
create procedure sp_exec_proc( 
in_proc char(64)
)
begin

set @proc = concat('CALL ',in_proc);
prepare stmt from @proc;
execute stmt;

end
```

You can then pass in the procedure name and optional parameters

```
call sp_exec_proc('sp_my_proc("ABC")')
```